# How can I count by 1 every time vol > 6

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js

I am trying to count up by 1 every time the mic hears a snap of a finger.

```js
    var sketch = function (p) {
      with(p) {

        var mic;
        var vol;
        var count = 0;

        p.setup = function() {
          createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

          mic = new p5.AudioIn();
          mic.start();
        };
    
        p.draw = function() {
          background('pink');

          vol = mic.getLevel(); // level is between 0 and 1
          vol = vol * 100;

          if (vol > 6) {
            count += 1;
            text(count, 60, 300);

            //if (count += 1) {
            //  vol = 0;
            //}

          } else {
            text(count, 60, 300);
          }
        };
     
      }
    };
    
    let node = document.createElement('div');
    window.document.getElementById('p5-container').appendChild(node);
    new p5(sketch, node);
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#efefef;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
<div id="p5-container"></div>
```

Issue:
with my current code, it continues to count for the duration of the finger snap sound. How can I write this to add 1 to var count only once per finger snap

Comment: You can create a variable to check if this is the same snap. Set it to a truthy value when you first hear the snap and set it to a falsy when the snap ends

Answer (score 0):

If you are counting when the volume goes above 6, then you need a flag to know when it has gone back down under that threshold.

So set a var like:

```
var waitingForVolumeIncrease = true;
```

Then in your code, when you increment the count, also set the flag to false.

Add another condition that checks if the volume is less than 6 that resets the flag to true.

Finally you only want to increase the count when the flag is set to true, so you need to update your check to ensure the flag is set to true.

Comment: Someone else beat me to it... getDate() is what you're looking for in your time diff logic.

Answer (score 0):

Record last snap start time and check if new snap has arrived after `old_snap_time + snap_duration` :

```
var mic;
var vol;
var count = 0;
var snapDurationMs = 500;
var lastSnap = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  strokeWeight(4);
  stroke('rgba(0,255,0,0.25)');
  fill(color(0, 0, 255));
  textSize(40);

  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start();
}

function draw() {
  background('pink');

  vol = mic.getLevel(); // level is between 0 and 1
  vol = vol * 100;

  let now = millis();

  if (vol > 25 && now - lastSnap > snapDurationMs) {
    count += 1;
    lastSnap = now;
  }

  text(count, 100, 300);
}
```

Btw, no need for else{} part in draw, because in that case you will loose some frames

**EDIT**

Changed constants a bit. With my mic reasonable threshold of sound was around `25%-30%` of input level, if it is lower - we start to detect random noise events in mic. Also snap duration changed to `500 ms`, because if it is shorter, we may start to count same snap twice or even more.

Even with these fixes, sometimes mic detects "ghost snap", because microphone is device with very low signal-to-noise ratio. So to get even more accuracy, different approach is needed, such as :

1. recording mic signal (level) continuously
2. converting it to frequency domain with Fourier transform
3. filtering out frequencies with low amplitudes
4. converting filtered signal back to time domain with IFT
5. comparing filtered signal with your *pre-recorded* finger snap profile
6. if these signals matches, then count++

But this algo is totally different story, so is out of scope here